# how can I remove suffix using the nltk package in python?

Tags: python, nltk, suffix

I changed "stem" to "suff", but it went wrong. Does anybody know how to use the suff fuction?

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
from nltk.stem import arlstem
    for j in range(0 , len(contextsWorld_1)):
        a = stemmer.stem(contextsWorld_1[j])
        contextsWorld_1_1.append(a)
    print(contextsWorld_1_1)
```

[the website of nltk.stem package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esTlG.png)
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXZKr.png)

Comment: No, I want to stem words in English. However, I just found the way to find the stem instead of removing suffix.

Comment: When I search for the method to remove suffix, I can only find the `suff` method which you said that it is only for Arebic. So how can I remove suffix?

Comment: Please replace the picture of the documentation by a link to the documention.

Answer (score 0):

[`suff`](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html#nltk.stem.arlstem.ARLSTem.suff) is a method of the [arlstem](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html#module-nltk.stem.arlstem) module, which is designed for stemming Arabic text.

If the goal is to remove the suffixes of English words, we want to stem them with something like the [English SnowballStemmer](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html#nltk.stem.snowball.EnglishStemmer.stem). Here is a minimal example:

```py
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer

words = ["running", "jumping", "playing"]
stemmed_words = []

stemmer = SnowballStemmer(language="english")

for word in words:
    a = stemmer.stem(word)
    stemmed_words.append(a)

print(stemmed_words)
```

Output:

```
['run', 'jump', 'play']
```